# How do you combine multiple Observables and get the results of all in a single subscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am making multiple calls to a RESTful service. Each call gets me a results. For example, it returns objects similar to the following:

```
{
     results: {
          name: "Joe",
          age: 10,     
     }
}
```

I am making 5 different calls to the service with different request parameters, and I only want to return the results to my program when all 5 calls have completed and returned their object. I would like to return to the application with an array of 5 objects like the the one above.

How can this be done in Angular 2 with Observables?

This is what I have tried just earlier but I cannot figure out why it won't work:

```
    getImage(imageUrl: string) {

        console.log("Fetching from " + imageUrl);

        return Observable.create((o) => {
            this.httpService.get(imageUrl)
            .map(res => {
                return res.json();
            })
            .map(res => res.photos.photo[0])
            .subscribe((result) => {
                console.log(this.generateImageUrl(result));
                o.next(this.generateImageUrl(result));
            });
        });
    }

    getImages(hashtags:string[]){
        var arrayOfObservables = [];
        for (var hashtag in hashtags){
            var url = this.flickrAPI.fetchImagesByTag + hashtags[hashtag];
            var query = this.getImage(url);
            arrayOfObservables.push(query);
        }
        console.log(arrayOfObservables);
        return Observable.forkJoin(arrayOfObservables, function(){
            console.log("Fork Join Done");
            return "from Fork Join with love";
        });
    }
```

And then the subscription part happens here

```
onSubmit() {
        // First, clear FeedItems
        this.feedItems = [];

        var tweets$ = this.twitterService.getTweets(this.hashtagInput);

        tweets$.subscribe((tweets) => {
            for (var i in tweets) {
                var hashtags = tweets[i].entities.hashtags;
                var flicks$ = this.flickrService.getImages(hashtags);
                this.subscribeToFlicks(flicks$, tweets[i]);
            }
        });
    }


    subscribeToFlicks(flicks$, tweet) {
        console.log("Here");
        flicks$.subscribe((results) => {
            console.log("Flickr Subscription:");
            console.log(results);

            var twitterItem = new TwitterData(tweet.user, tweet.text);
            var flickrItem = new FlickrData("null", results);

            var feedItem = new FeedItem(twitterItem, flickrItem);

            this.feedItems.push(feedItem);
        });
    }
```

Comment: what does "it won't work" mean? What's it doing instead?

Comment: @by not working, I mean nothing is happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, you need to remove the second parameter of the `forkJoin` method:

```
getImages(hashtags:string[]){
    var arrayOfObservables = [];
    for (var hashtag in hashtags){
        var url = this.flickrAPI.fetchImagesByTag + hashtags[hashtag];
        var query = this.getImage(url);
        arrayOfObservables.push(query);
    }
    console.log(arrayOfObservables);
    return Observable.forkJoin(arrayOfObservables);
}
```

The second parameter corresponds to the `resultSelector`. It allow you (if you want) to create the result returned by forkJoin when all events are received. If not specified, it will return the results as an array.

And subscribe on the returned observable:

```
getImages().subscribe(() => {
  console.log("Fork Join Done");
});
```

Because an observable is lazy, without subscribing nothing will be executed...

**Edit**

You could update the étiAge method this way:

```
    getImage(imageUrl: string) {

        console.log("Fetching from " + imageUrl);

        return this.httpService.get(imageUrl)
            .map(res => {
                return res.json();
            })
            .map(res => res.photos.photo[0])
            .map(res => this.generateImageUrl(res));
    }
```

Comment: I am subscribing to `getImages`, in a different part of the code (the code that calls the function is returned an observable and then subscribe is called on it)

Comment: And nothing is executed? Why don't you directly return `this.httpService.get(...` within `getImage` without creating a raw observable? Could you add in your question the way you subscribe on the observable returned by `getImages`? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! You want only to have get image requests to be executed in parallel?

Comment: Exactly. The getImages function needs to return an array of img URLs to the component that calls it. `getImages` therefore needs to make several parallel calls to `getImage()`

Comment: Okay. And the callback of the second subscribe isn't called?

Comment: That's right. It was not even printing `"Here"` However since I've implemented your advice to not create a new Observable in `getImage` it is printing `Here`. I think that may have been the issue. Still confused as to why though

Comment: Yes, it works. Just sorting out some type issues and formatting but ya it's getting the data properly!

Comment: It was your second comment that proved correct. Can you update your answer so I can accept? Also I would really aprreciate if you could explain why creating a new Observable to wrap the `http` get call was doing nothing (I was subscribing to it afteralla and calling `next()`)